# configuring log4j.xml from different location other than classpath in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am using sl4j logger print logs in file, I have following log4j.xml file configured, as I am deploying my spring application on JBOSS it doesn't create directory structure like tomcat so I am not able to configure debug level of log, I want to my application to pick the log4j.xml from different location like d:\configuration so that I can configure debug level for my application how can I do it ? I am not having web.xml. **I have tried using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class but it gives error as file not found though file is present**

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="file" value="/home/client/webApp.log"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="5MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
       </layout>
    </appender>
<root>
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i load my log4j.xml file which is not in classpath and it present in D drive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365180/how-can-i-load-my-log4j-xml-file-which-is-not-in-classpath-and-it-present-in-d-d)

Comment: My application is spring boot application so didn't have web.xml

Comment: Do have a look at the answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42695875/1910582) (*I have retracted the duplicate flag post additional information provided*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in `application.properties` set a property viz. `server.context_parameters.log4jConfigLocation=path/to/log4j.xml`.

Then implement a listener class `Log4jConfigListener` as below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;

public class Log4jConfigListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletcontextevent) {
        LogManager.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletcontextevent)     {

        ServletContext context = servletcontextevent.getServletContext();

        String path = null;

        path = context.getInitParameter("log4jConfigLocation");

        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pathResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Resource[] resources = null;
        try {
            resources = pathResolver.getResources(path);

            for (Resource resource : resources) {
                File file = resource.getFile();
                path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                break; // read only the first configuration
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            context.log("Unable to load log4j configuration file", e);
        }

        LogManager.resetConfiguration();
        DOMConfigurator.configure(path);
    }

}
```

Next register the listener in configuration class as `@Bean`

```
@Bean
public Log4jConfigListener log4jConfigListener() {
   return new Log4jConfigListener();
}
```

Update `pom.xml` to exclude default logback configuration and include the log4j as below

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Let know in comments for any more information.

**P.S.**: For non Spring Boot (*or with traditional `web.xml`*) refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30369096/1910582)

Comment: I Have tried it but logs are printed on stdout not in the file not in the file I am deploying it on jboss

Comment: Please refer the updated answer for modifications in `pom.xml`

Comment: sorry for late reply but I am not getting logs in file and there is no error..!

Comment: I am able to configure and run the setup with Spring Boot ver `1.5.1.RELEASE`, spring-boot-starter-log4j ver. `1.3.8.RELEASE` and JDK `1.8.0_121`

Comment: One quick check I could suggest is whether the `Log4jConfigListener` bean is picked up or not.

Comment: The bean should look like something `{"bean":"log4jConfigListener","aliases":[],"scope":"singleton","type":"com.example.so.Log4jConfigListener","resource":"com.example.so.DemoApplication","dependencies":[]}` in actuator endpoint `/beans`

Comment: how could I view bean ? shall I print it using toString() ?

Comment: Use spring boot actuator (*available out-of-box*) endpoint `/beans` to list all the configured beans. For local setup it looks like `http://localhost:8080/beans`

Comment: I Have checked the bean object I am not getting any of these properties/values in Object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138017/discussion-between-shailesh-and-bond-java-bond).